# Changing method from nonvirtual to virtual may cause unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, clr

I read in CLR via C# 4th edition on chapter 6:

> If you define a method as nonvirtual, you should never change the
>   method to virtual in the future. The reason is because some compilers
>   will call the nonvirtual method by using the call instruction instead
>   of the callvirt instruction. If the method changes from nonvirtual to
>   virtual and the referencing code is not recompiled, the virtual method
>   will be called nonvirtually, causing the application to produce
>   unpredictable behavior. If the referencing code is written in C#, this
>   is not a problem, because C# calls all instance methods by using
>   callvirt. But this could be a problem if the referencing code was
>   written using a different programming language.

but I can't quite figure out what kind of unpredictable behavior may occur?
Can you get an example or explain what kind of unexpected behavior is the author is referring to?

Comment: The worst thing I can imagine, is if someone consumes the original assembly and calls non-virtually, then they take in a new assembly version (without recompiling!) where the method is virtual and actually overridden, the "unexpected" behavior is that the override is not called ... Addition: I do not see a big issue in practice. If people "upgrade" to a newer version of the assembly, they should either recompile their code or be prepared to tolerate strange results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.call%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the call OpCode indicate that it acceptable to call a virtual method non-virtually. It will just invoke the method based on the compiled type in the IL rather runtime type information.

However, from what I can tell the method will fail verification if you call a virtual method non-virtually. Here is a short test program where we will dynamically emit the IL for invoking a method (either virtually or non-virtually), compile, and run it:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Base parameter, Base method info
        CreateAndInvokeMethod(false, new Base(), typeof(Base), typeof(Base).GetMethod("Test"));
        CreateAndInvokeMethod(true, new Base(), typeof(Base), typeof(Base).GetMethod("Test"));
        CreateAndInvokeMethod(false, new C(), typeof(Base), typeof(Base).GetMethod("Test"));
        CreateAndInvokeMethod(true, new C(), typeof(Base), typeof(Base).GetMethod("Test"));
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Base parameter, C method info
        CreateAndInvokeMethod(false, new Base(), typeof(Base), typeof(C).GetMethod("Test"));
        CreateAndInvokeMethod(true, new Base(), typeof(Base), typeof(C).GetMethod("Test"));
        CreateAndInvokeMethod(false, new C(), typeof(Base), typeof(C).GetMethod("Test"));
        CreateAndInvokeMethod(true, new C(), typeof(Base), typeof(C).GetMethod("Test"));
        Console.WriteLine();

        // C parameter, C method info
        CreateAndInvokeMethod(false, new C(), typeof(C), typeof(C).GetMethod("Test"));
        CreateAndInvokeMethod(true, new C(), typeof(C), typeof(C).GetMethod("Test"));
    }

    private static void CreateAndInvokeMethod(bool useVirtual, Base instance, Type parameterType, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var dynMethod = new DynamicMethod("test", typeof (string), 
            new Type[] { parameterType });
        var gen = dynMethod.GetILGenerator();
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        OpCode code = useVirtual ? OpCodes.Callvirt : OpCodes.Call;
        gen.Emit(code, methodInfo);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        string res;
        try
        {
            res = (string)dynMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { instance });
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            var e = ex.InnerException;
            res = string.Format("{0}: {1}", e.GetType(), e.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("UseVirtual: {0}, Result: {1}", useVirtual, res);
    }   
}

public class Base
{
    public virtual string Test()
    {
        return "Base";
    }
}

public class C : Base
{
    public override string Test()
    {
        return "C";
    }
}
```

The output:

> UseVirtual: False, Result: System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.
>   UseVirtual: True, Result: Base
>   UseVirtual: False, Result: System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.
>   UseVirtual: True, Result: C
>
> UseVirtual: False, Result: System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.
>   UseVirtual: True, Result: System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.
>   UseVirtual: False, Result: System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.
>   UseVirtual: True, Result: System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.
>
> UseVirtual: False, Result: System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.
>   UseVirtual: True, Result: C

Answer (score 1):

If a virtual method would be called as a nonvirtual method, that would change which method that would actually be called.

When you call a virtual method, it's the actual type of the object that determines which method is called, but when you call a nonvirtual method it's the type of the reference that determines which method is called.

Lets say that we have a base class and a subclass:

```
public class BaseClass {

  public virtual void VMedthod() {
    Console.WriteLine("base");
  }

}

public class SubClass : BaseClass {

  public override void VMethod() {
    Console.WriteLine("sub");
  }

}
```

If you have a reference of the type of the base class, assigns it an instance of the subclass, and call the method, it's the overriding method that will be called:

```
BaseClass x = new SubClass();
x.VMethod(); // shows "sub"
```

If the virtual method would be called as a nonvirtual method instead, it would call the method in the base class insetad and show "base".

This is a simplified example of course, you would have the base class in one library and the subclass in another for the problem to possibly occur.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you make a library with the following classes:

```
// Version 1

public class Fruit {
    public void Eat() {
        // eats fruit.
    }
    // ...
}

public class Watermelon : Fruit { /* ... */ }
public class Strawberry : Fruit { /* ... */ }
```

Supposed the end-user of the library writes a method that takes a `Fruit` and calls its `Eat()` method. Its compiler see a non-virtual function call and emits a `call` instruction.

Now later you decide that eating a strawberry and eating a watermelon are, um, rather different, so you do something like:

```
//Version 2

public class Fruit {
    public virtual void Eat() {
        // this isn't supposed to be called
        throw NotImplementedException(); 
    }
}

public class Watermelon : Fruit { 
    public override void Eat() {
        // cuts it into pieces and then eat it
    }
    // ...
}
public class Strawberry : Fruit {
    public override void Eat() {
        // wash it and eat it.
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now your end-user's code suddenly crashes with a `NotImplementedException`, because non-virtual calls on a base class reference always go to the base class method, and everyone is bewildered because your end-user only used `Watermelon` and `Strawberry` for its `Fruit`s and both have fully implemented `Eat()` methods...